# Can't find ElasticSearch 6.0+ option in magento 2.3.1 backend (CE)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch into my server using the following guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

So I have elasticsearch 6.7 installed right now but inside my Magento 2.3.1 (CE) backend I can only see this:

**Search Engine**

- MYSQL
- Elasticsearch
- Elasticsearch 5.0+

I also updated my composer.json file with:

**"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0|~5.1|~6.7"**

I want to fix this problem because when I run the reindex this happens:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Enabling [_all] is disabled in 6.0. As a replacement, you can use [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Enabling [_all] is disabled in 6.0. As a replacement, you can use [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field."},"status":400}
```

And I think the source is probably this difference between the versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mrg/ce/Elasticsearch6.html

you probably have this module disabled somehow:

> Magento_Elasticsearch**6**

Magento 2.3.1 default search modules:

```
Magento_Search
Magento_CatalogSearch
Magento_AdvancedSearch
Magento_Elasticsearch
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_Elasticsearch6
```

please check your modules:

```
bin/magento module:status
bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6
bin/magento cache:clean
```

=========================================

> debug

if you check your modules folder:

```
ls -l vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-6/
```

and its empty, depends on your circumstances, you can try to install this module:

```
su magenx -s /bin/bash -c "composer require magento/module-elasticsearch-6"
Using version ^100.3 for magento/module-elasticsearch-6               
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing magento/module-elasticsearch-6 (100.3.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried to check if the module Magento_Elasticsearch6 was installed and/or enabled but with a quick bin/magento module:status I can't really find it. Shouldn't my composer require (from my post) install it or am I missing something?

Comment: check updated answer. probably you dont have this module in codebase.

Comment: Thank you very much, your updated answer solve my problem! Accepted